# Facebook App for Personal Use - Without app review process

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I want to automatically publish content from my internal back office system to my Facebook page.

What I understand is that I have to create a Facebook app with the permissions pages_manage_ads, pages_manage_metadata, pages_read_engagement, pages_read_user_content, pages_manage_posts, pages_manage_engagement, publish_video.

Is there a way so, I can skip the Facebook review process, because I just want to publish video to my pages, not to the public.

I don't want it to use by the public, just pushing to my pages through my app, no third party use.

Earlier it was working fine without the app review process, but in recent facebook changes it requires app review for personal use also.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: what about all those permissions? you do not need all those just to publish videos...but yes, you do need app review nowadays.